# react-table: UI gets re-rendered on using pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-table

I am trying to implement a react-table pagination example from the react-table documentation.
I am also using react-redux to manage the data. The table gets displayed fine but as soon as any of the pagination controls are clicked the page gets refreshed, `useEffect()` is called, and react-table re-renders and resets to it's initial pagination state.
I am using `React.useMemo()` but the UI still gets re-rendered.
I would like to know how the page refresh can be prevented when interacting with the pagination controls.

My sample code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { userActions } from './actions';
import { useTable, usePagination, useRowSelect } from 'react-table'

function Products() {
  const allProducts = useSelector(state => state.users.allProducts);
  const memorizedProducts = React.useMemo(() => allProducts, [allProducts]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userActions.getAllProducts());
  }, []);

  const columns = React.useMemo(
      () => [
              {
                Header: 'Id',
                accessor: 'cell.productId',
              },
              {
                Header: 'Name',
                accessor: 'cell.name',
              }
          ],
      []
    );

  return (
      <ProductsTable columns={columns} data={memorizedProducts}/>
      );
}

const ProductsTable = ({columns, data}) => {
  if (!data) {
    return null;
  }
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page, // Instead of using 'rows', we'll use page,
    // which has only the rows for the active page

    // The rest of these things are super handy, too ;)
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    selectedFlatRows,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize, selectedRowIds },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    usePagination,
    useRowSelect,
    hooks => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
        // Let's make a column for selection
        {
          id: 'selection',
          // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
          // to render a checkbox
          Header: ({ getToggleAllPageRowsSelectedProps }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllPageRowsSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
          // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
          // to the render a checkbox
          Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
        },
        ...columns,
      ])
    }
  )

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <>
      <div className="productsListDiv">
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {/*
        Pagination can be built however you'd like.
        This is just a very basic UI implementation:
      */}
      <div className="pagination">
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>'}
        </button>{' '}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>>'}
        </button>{' '}
        <span>
          Page{' '}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{' '}
        </span>
        <span>
          | Go to page:{' '}
          <input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={e => {
              const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
              gotoPage(page)
            }}
            style={{ width: '100px' }}
          />
        </span>{' '}
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
  ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
    const defaultRef = React.useRef()
    const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef

    React.useEffect(() => {
      resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate
    }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate])

    return (
      <>
        <input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
      </>
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I hate react-table. It has lots of problems...